# Is there full documentation for Socrata SODA SDK?

Tags: android, socrata

I've been through the SODA Android SDK's GitHub page, and [README](https://github.com/socrata/soda-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md).

Is there more developer documentation or is this it?  If this is it, is it common to find `light-touch` documentation like this? and is this is recommended  to read the actual source code to understand what's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `soda-android` library is actually pretty old at this point, and I'd recommend instead just building a simple client using the [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library on our RESTful API. I've heard great feedback about using that library with our API.